# Select2 with multi select option only allows me to write 2 characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 v4.0.7 and setting up a multi select with the option to dynamically create tags like so:

```
<select id="role-select" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

and I initialize the select2 like so:

```
$('#role-select').select2({
    tags: true
});
```

All this is set up in a Laravel 5.8 environment and I'm using CDNs for select2.

The problem is that when I try to write in the select option I can't type more than 2 characters.

Is there something I'm doing wrong o not doing?

> ### Update

Has anyone been able to reproduce this error???

Extra information: Webserver is an ubuntu 16.04 box using apache2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select2 v4.0.7 and jQuery 3.4.1 are incompatible. If you use jQuery ~3.3.1 then it works.

See also https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5485

Comment: This is now fixed in select2 4.0.8 (i.e. you can use jQuery 3.4.1 and the tagging works as expected again). See https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.8.